# How to view details from mysql database when i check the checkboxes for my webpage?

Tags: mysql, checkbox

i want to create a event where when i check the checkboxes and submit it,then it should display the selected details from mysql database.
So,if anyone can help me out,please....

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could narrow your question to a specific area with which you have difficulty, you'll receive a positive response. Please post any relevant code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bridge table that contains all Id's of the form and a boolean of checked or unchecked (1,0) you would repeat the entry for form ID and add the id of the tag (checkbox).  If you want to query the results to populate the information you would use this:
    SELECT tag_id  From Bridge  Where form_id = 12; 
This would return all the tag_id's that where checked from your webpage.

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Comment: Of course, here is an example:
BridgeTable:
id, form_id, form
Form_id:
Form_id's (male, female, age group, so on)
Form/Page/user (however you are tracking the form)
idz